# How to grant permissions on a MySQL database by foreign key value

Tags: mysql, system-administration

I'm administering a MySQL database for a handful of different users. At the moment, I have a table which specifies user information. This table is then referenced as a foreign key by all downstream tables. This way it is possible to see for all data entries who this data belongs to. I would like to grant permissions so that each user can SELECT all data in the database - ie, they can share and see each other's data. However, I don't want the users to be able to modify other users inputs, so they can only DELETE and INSERT data that references their own username in the users table. Is it possible to grant permissions in this way, or is there another way of achieving this desired effect?

Comment: I think you will have to do this as part of your application code. I assume there is an application the users use and you are not talking about users accessing the database directly?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for row-level security, which MySQL doesn't support natively.  Either you could enforce your logic in the application layer, or explore the use of views (for example, see https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/protect-your-data-row-level-security-in-mariadb-10-0/)

Comment: I would also add that this would work if the users table is the mysql's own users table, i.e. the application maps its users to mysql user accounts. This is rare, unless you use some kind of a single sign on (SSO) to authenticate to mysql.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I'm building an application based on DataJoint so that users can easily upload and query scientific data using a GUI or python connector. I will see if this can be implemented easily in the application, but the blog post on views also looks promising.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.